# It looks like python 3.11 is slower than 3.9 version

Tags: python, version

This is sample code what i use.
It has the ability to extract phrases containing specific words from numerous text files.
Also, It actually runs within pyqt5.

```
f = open(self.foldername + "\\!!search.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8")
    f.close()
    data2 = ""
    filelist = os.listdir(self.foldername)
    file_list = [file for file in filelist if file.endswith(".txt")]
    length = len(file_list)
    self.i = 0
    while file_list != []:
        file = file_list.pop(0)
        try:
            f = open(self.foldername + "\\" + file, "r+", encoding="utf-8")
            data = f.readlines()
            for step in range(len(data)):
                if (len(data[step]) < 200) and (self.a in data[step]) and (self.b in data[step]) and \
                        (self.c in data[step]) and (self.d in data[step]) and (self.e in data[step]) \
                        and (self.k not in data[step]) and \
                        (self.l not in data[step]) and (self.m not in data[step]) and (self.n not in data[step]) and \
                        (self.o not in data[step]):
                    a = open(self.foldername + "\\!!search.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
                    a.write(file + " : " + data[step] + "\n")
                    a.close()
            f.close()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            try:
                f = open(self.foldername + "\\" + file, "r+", encoding="ansi")
                data = f.readlines()
                for step in range(len(data)):
                    if (len(data[step]) < 200) and (self.a in data[step]) and (self.b in data[step]) and \
                            (self.c in data[step]) and (self.d in data[step]) and (self.e in data[step]) \
                            and (self.k not in data[step]) and \
                            (self.l not in data[step]) and (self.m not in data[step]) \
                            and (self.n not in data[step]) and (self.o not in data[step]):
                        a = open(self.foldername + "\\!!search.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
                        a.write(file + " : " + data[step] + "\n")
                        a.close()
                f.close()
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                try:
                    f = open(self.foldername + "\\" + file, "r+", encoding="utf-16")
                    data = f.readlines()
                    for step in range(len(data)):
                        if (len(data[step]) < 200) and (self.a in data[step]) and (self.b in data[step]) and \
                                (self.c in data[step]) and (self.d in data[step]) and (self.e in data[step]) \
                                and (self.k not in data[step]) and \
                                (self.l not in data[step]) and (self.m not in data[step]) \
                                and (self.n not in data[step]) and (self.o not in data[step]):
                            a = open(self.foldername + "\\!!search.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
                            a.write(file + " : " + data[step] + "\n")
                            a.close()
                    f.close()
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    try:
                        f = open(self.foldername + "\\" + file, "r+", encoding="utf-16-le")
                        data = f.readlines()
                        for step in range(len(data)):
                            if (len(data[step]) < 200) and (self.a in data[step]) and (self.b in data[step]) and \
                                    (self.c in data[step]) and (self.d in data[step]) and (self.e in data[step]) \
                                    \ and (self.k not in data[step]) and (self.l not in data[step]) and (
                                    self.m not in data[step]) \
                                    and (self.n not in data[step]) and (self.o not in data[step]):
                                a = open(self.foldername + "\\!!search.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
                                a.write(file + " : " + data[step] + "\n")
                                a.close()
                        f.close()
                    except UnicodeDecodeError:
                        data2 = data2 + file + "\n\n"
```

It is well-working in python 3.9 but very slow in >=3.10 version.

Of course I know this isn't a good code.
I also know that the question is not clear.

But there's no way to explain it in more detail.
If possible, may I know why this is happening?
I'm sorry. Thank you.